# the fill function doesn"t seem to work i'm trying to convert ADN code to ARN then fill it into an array and print it

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

the fill function doesn"t seem to work i'm trying to convert ADN code to ARN then fill it into an array and print it
HERE IS THE CODE
`https://pastebin.com/w2Ru1eCY`

```
from numpy import *
def saisie ():#fonction  pour saisir la taille de tableau avec controle de saisie 
    n=int(input("donne la taille de tableau:"))
    while not (5<= n <= 30):
        n=int(input("donne la taille 2 tableau:"))
    return n
#<fonction pour remplir le tableau____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________>
def  remplir(T,n): 
    for i in range (n) :
        a=str(T[i])
        a = (input("donner un valeur"))
        while a not in ["A","U","G","C"]:
            a = (input("donner un valeur correcte "))
    return T
#<____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________>
def affiche (T,n):
    for i in range (n):
        a=str(T[i])
        print(a,end="/")
    return T
#<____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________>
def conv(T,Tarn,n):
    for i in range (n):
        a=str(T[i])
        if a =="A":
            Tarn[i]="U"
        if a =="U":
            Tarn[i]="A"
        if a =="C":
            Tarn[i]="G"
        if a =="G":
            Tarn[i]="C"
    return Tarn
#<programme principale____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________>
n=saisie()
T=array([0]*int(n))
Tarn=array([0]*int(n))
remplir(T,n)
affiche(Tarn,n)
```

i need to help to make the fill function do its job

Comment: Where is the fill function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.